# ActionController::Parameters deprecation warning: Method size is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I recently came across this deprecation warning

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Method size is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1, as `ActionController::Parameters` no longer inherits from hash. Using this deprecated behavior exposes potential security problems. If you continue to use this method you may be creating a security vulnerability in your app that can be exploited.

Params looked like this:

```
<ActionController::Parameters { "objects" => 
  <ActionController::Parameters {
    "0"=>{"priority"=>"24", "style"=>"three_pictures"}, 
    "1"=>{"priority"=>"24", "style"=>"three_pictures"}, 
    "2"=>{"priority"=>"24", "style"=>"three_pictures"}
} permitted: false> } permitted: false>
```

And I tried to find the size of `objects` like this:
`params[:objects].size`

And then I tried the same thing with `length` and `count`, which results in the same warning. What would be the work around for this? `.keys.length` is something that works, but is this the correct way to do it or am I missing something here?

Comment: you can convert `params to hash` using `to_h` and access those methods.

Comment: ` Rails 5 ActionController::Parameters` now returns an Object instead of a Hash.
`To access the parameters in the object you can add to_h to the parameters:`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you have to convert `params` to Hash since in Rails 5 `params` no longer inherits from `Hash`. So `.size`, `.length` and `.count` won't work on params directly.

How to convert it to `Hash` (shorter code may be possible):

```
permitted_params = params.require(:your_model_name).permit(
  :product_inspirationals => [
    :priority, 
    :style
  ]
).to_h

puts permitted_params[:product_inspirationals].length
```

Don't know about your model structure so you have to adjust it to your needs.

Answer (score -1):

For hash, you can find the size by `.size` method.

The problem is not with the size method here, Problem is in the `ActionController::Parameters` which is not hash,

---

Look at the first line inside `ActionController::Parameters`

```
"0"=>{priority"=>"24", "style"=>"three_pictures"}
```

it should be following as `"` missing before `priority`

```
"0"=>{"priority"=>"24", "style"=>"three_pictures"}
```

After this `.size method` should be working